# xcode - with multiple test targets what does the scheme test do

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, targets

Im uncertain what the schema test does when clicking on edit schema.  My project has multiple test targets.  I have tried checking them  off in the schema but  unchecking them affects nothing. My question is what does the test schema menu really do ??

Here is an image how to get to the schema menu:

[image]

and here is the actual menu im having difficulty to understand its purpose:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes which tests are run when selecting Product -> Test (or cmd + U) for the given scheme.